# Death of a Jane or John doe

Tags: united-states, law

I enjoy watching cop dramas and in *The Closer* (Season 1, Episode 12), a criminal might be exonerated because authorities mis-identified the body of a victim. In American legal history has anyone been charged with the murder of an unidentifiable body, a Jane or John Doe? If so, does it happen frequently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [List of unidentified murder victims in the United States](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unidentified_murder_victims_in_the_United_States):

> **Union County Jane Doe**
>
> A woman between 17 and 21 died on 10 July 1991 in El Dorado, Arkansas.
>   The decedent used multiple names, including Cheryl Ann Wick (which she
>   used from a stolen identification card), Kelly Carr and Shannon Wiley.
>   She was known to have lived in various states prior to her death,
>   including Texas, where she apparently worked as a prostitute. Other
>   reports explain she had been arrested in the past, using several of
>   her aliases and had possibly been involved in a bank robbery on the
>   East Coast.[4] She had been shot by her boyfriend who was **convicted** of
>   the murder but she remains **unidentified**.
>
> **St. Petersburg Jane Doe**
>
> A 11 to 20-year-old girl who was pushed in front of a vehicle in St.
>   Petersburg, Pinellas County, Florida, on 9 June 1973. Her wavy hair
>   was auburn and shoulder length; her eyes were a vibrant blue. She wore
>   two earrings in one ear, a piercing in her other ear had healed. She
>   wore a ring missing its stone as well as a multicolored gown and
>   purple tights. It is possible that she was a runaway; some believe she
>   was from North Carolina or Virginia, as she told many inconsistent
>   stories. The victim was known by many names when she was alive,
>   including Janice Marie Brock, Marie, Maria and Cindy. It is also
>   suspected that she was involved with a drug activity, which may have
>   been a reason for her murder. Although her murderer, Lawrence Dorn,
>   was **convicted** of her death, the girl currently remains
>   **unidentified**.

It appears that there are about a 100 currently unidentified murder victims in the US (that the wikipedia editors bothers to collect).
Given that there are ~ 15k homicides in the US annually, I don't think there is much statistical significance here: it is rare for a victim to remain unidentified and it is very rare for such a crime to be solved.

Comment: of course there's a larger body of dead people who remain unidentified where there's no murder investigation launched. Think illegals found dead in the deserts north of the Mexican border, most die from dehydration.